# JavaScript Simple code, Uncaught TypeError: bButtonR.addEventListener is not a function at index.html

Tags: javascript

So I wanted to to make a banner container that flicks through multiple banners (3atm), I'm sure most users will be able to understand through the simple code alone. This isn't the final at all but I at least need a working starting point. the error is "Uncaught TypeError: bButtonR.addEventListener is not a function at index.html"

```
        const bannerItem1 = document.querySelectorAll("#bItem1");
const bannerItem2 = document.querySelectorAll("#bItem2");
const bannerItem3 = document.querySelectorAll("#bItem3");
const bButtonL = document.querySelectorAll(".left-arrow");
const bButtonR = document.querySelectorAll(".right-arrow");
let iCounter = 1;

bButtonR.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    iCounter++;
    updateBanner();
});

function updateBanner() {
  if (iCounter > 3) {
        iCounter = 3;
    } else if(iCounter === 1) {
        bannerItem2.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem1.style.display = "flex";
    } else if (iCounter === 2) {
        bannerItem1.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem2.style.display = "flex";
    }
      else if (iCounter === 3) {
        bannerItem1.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem2.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "flex";
    } 
};
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a collection of elements, to get single element use `document.querySelector` instead. The element reference will allow to add event listener.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) return a list.
If want to select only one element you should use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or, even better, [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
getElementById is much faster than querySelector and if you do not have any specific reason to use querySelector and you know you will use and id and not a dynamic css selector you should use it.
Try this:

```
const bannerItem1 = document.getElementById("bItem1");
const bannerItem2 = document.getElementById("bItem2");
const bannerItem3 = document.getElementById("bItem3");
const bButtonL = document.querySelector(".left-arrow");
const bButtonR = document.querySelector(".right-arrow");
let iCounter = 1;

bButtonR.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    iCounter++;
    updateBanner();
});

function updateBanner() {
  if (iCounter > 3) {
        iCounter = 3;
    } else if(iCounter === 1) {
        bannerItem2.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem1.style.display = "flex";
    } else if (iCounter === 2) {
        bannerItem1.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem2.style.display = "flex";
    }
      else if (iCounter === 3) {
        bannerItem1.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem2.style.display = "none";
        bannerItem3.style.display = "flex";
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

const bButtonL = document.querySelectorAll(".left-arrow");
if the class "left-arrow" is a single class then you must have to use

```
bButtonR[0].addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    iCounter++;
    updateBanner();
});
```

because queryselectorall will put your class in an array . and to access that you should use indexing .

and if one class with same name is there you should use getelementsbyclassname or queryselector not queryselectorall .

```
const bButtonL = document.querySelector(".left-arrow");
bButtonR.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        iCounter++;
        updateBanner();
    });
```

Comment: *"because queryselectorall will put your class in an array"* - that's simply wrong. Kindly, read the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) before posting misleading info.

Comment: *"and if one class with same name is there you should use getelementsbyclassname or queryselector not queryselectorall"* - wrong, once again. Please read the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: yes,i agree , i am misconcepted . then what will return queryselectorall. when i console the queryselectorall then it is printing an array of targeted elements .

Comment: what misconception i have about queryselectorall and queryselector

Comment: Please read the docs for [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: What I understand when I read your explanation: *"because queryselectorall will put your class in an array"*, is that `document.querySelectorAll(".right-arrow")` will return `[right-arrow]`, an array containing the class as you said **which is wrong**. Kindly, read the docs before posting wrong/misleading explanations.

Comment: thank you for your words. definitely,i will go through the links for better knowledge

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for being open-minded and for considering my advice. Have a nice day!

Comment: thank you for the help, it works, now I have a starting point, cheers.